# Excel table with a dynamically generated column header for each month between given start and end date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data which gives the number of particular items required between a start and end date. I would like to create a table (possibly a pivot table) where each month within the range is shown and the number of items are available.

I am giving the dates below in MM/YY format

| Name | Qty | start date | end date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table | 7 | 08/23 | 09/23 |
| chair | 2 | 07/23 | 10/23 |
| table | 10 | 09/23 | 10/23 |

In the 'pivot' table this would give

| Name | 07/23 | 08/23 | 09/23 | 10/23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chair | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| table | 0 | 7 | 17 | 10 |

I haven't been able to get the table to dynamically generate months between the max and min range.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be there is a more elegant way of doing this using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>, but yes you can easily accomplish this task.

[image]

---

To perform the task using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>, follow the steps:

---

- First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the **Power Query** window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Qty", Int64.Type}, {"start date", type date}, {"end date", type date}}),

    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each {Number.From([start date])..Number.From([end date])}),

    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),

    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Custom", type date}}),

    #"Inserted Start of Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Start of Month", each Date.StartOfMonth([Custom]), type date),

    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Start of Month", "Custom.1", each if [Custom] = [Start of Month] then [Start of Month] else null),

    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Conditional Column", each [Custom.1] <> null and [Custom.1] <> ""),

    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"start date", "end date", "Custom", "Custom.1"}),

    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"Start of Month", Order.Ascending}, {"Name", Order.Ascending}}),
    
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Start of Month", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Start of Month", type text}}, "en-US")[#"Start of Month"]), "Start of Month", "Qty", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

You can also accomplish this using formula and it will dynamically work. Functions used viz. <kbd>MAKEARRAY( )</kbd> , <kbd>SORT( )</kbd>, <kbd>UNIQUE( )</kbd>, <kbd>VSTACK( )</kbd>, <kbd>TOROW( )</kbd>, <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd>, <kbd>HSTACK( )</kbd> & <kbd>LET( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A2:A4,
     b,B2:B4,
     c,C2:C4,
     d,D2:D4,
     ua,SORT(UNIQUE(a)),
     ubc,SORT(UNIQUE(TOROW((c,d)),1),,,1),
     sum,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(ua),COLUMNS(ubc),LAMBDA(x,y,
         SUM((INDEX(ua,x)=a)*(INDEX(ubc,y)>=c)*(INDEX(ubc,y)<=d)*b))),
     HSTACK(VSTACK("Name",ua),VSTACK(ubc,sum)))
```

---

File to download : **[Excel](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cjm-ZRl3hbD0uYU-X?e=Es1r13)**

Comment: I've just tried your Power Query solution and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!